# Export and import GHCi session

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there a way to save my current GHCi session to a file? Maybe even import it next time when I open GHCi again?

I could probably resort to `head -n 42 ~/.ghc/ghci_history | tac` but that's kind-of hacky.

Comment: Have you checked out [IHaskell](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/notebooks/IHaskell.ipynb)?

Comment: Well, I know about it and considered it too much trouble for just occasional prototyping needs. But the more I read of it, the more relevant it seems.